# Adaptivecard keep text after submit

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

Is there a way to keep the text of an adpativecard in Teams after submitting an Input.ChoiceSet?

I'm posting automated to a teams channel and other team members should be able to see the submitted card without posting a new version.

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Poll Request",
        "id": "Title",
        "spacing": "Medium",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
        "size": "ExtraLarge",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "color": "Accent"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Neue Bayernmeldung für BR-Text",
        "id": "acHeaderTagLine",
        "separator": true
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Poll Header",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "size": "ExtraLarge",
        "spacing": "None",
        "id": "acHeader"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Hier steht die Meldung. ",
        "id": "acInstructions",
        "wrap": true
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Poll Question",
        "id": "acPollQuestion"
    },
    {
        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
        "placeholder": "Select from these choices",
        "choices": [
            {
                "title": "Choice 1",
                "value": "Choice 1"
            },
            {
                "title": "Choice 2",
                "value": "Choice 2"
            },
            {
                "title": "Choice 3",
                "value": "Choice 3"
            }
        ],
        "id": "acPollChoices",
        "style": "expanded"
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Submit",
        "id": "btnSubmit",
```

"data": {
"msteams": {
"type": "imBack",
"value": "Text to reply in chat"
}
}
}
]
}

Comment: So post a card back with the selected values. That way, people can see it. No submit button, no actions, just the selected values. That’s how it works.

Comment: Thx! Posting a card back would post a new one? Or would it update the existing one? We don't want to double the communication so we try to update the existing card.

Comment: You can update a card with a new one. Check the teams operations.